# ListView esconderse por detras de Fondo_Gradient y GoogleMaps Location

Tags: flutter, dart

Buenas noches, Tengo dos inconvenientes:

1) Mi List View se muestra por encima del fondo_gradient, y quiero que se "esconda" por detrás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa en la foto, la descripción larga, la barra con botones, maps los tengo dentro de un ListView y me gustaría que se esconda detrás del fondo de arriba.

Código:

```
class lista_negocio_detalle extends StatefulWidget {
  final Negocio value;

  lista_negocio_detalle({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _lista_negocio_detalle createState() => _lista_negocio_detalle();
}

class _lista_negocio_detalle extends State<lista_negocio_detalle> {
  GoogleMapController myController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          gradiente_fondo(widget.value.title),
          imagen_negocio(widget.value.imageUrl),
           ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              descripcion_detalle(widget.value.description),
              fila_botones(widget.value.celular,widget.value.facebook,widget.value.x,widget.value.y),
              map(widget.value.x, widget.value.y),
            ],
          ),

    ]));
  }
}
```

2) El segundo problema es que no encuentro en la documentación de GoogleMaps como poner(icono o cualquier cosa) la localización que le paso para el focus.
Es decir, tengo las coordenadas pero no se como mostrar con un icono.

Codigo:

```
child: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: (controller) {
          setState(() {
            myController = controller;
          });
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        compassEnabled: false,
        trackCameraPosition: true,

        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          tilt: (25.0),
          zoom: 15.9,
          target: LatLng(double.parse(x), double.parse(y)),

        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que se esconda , pues cambia el orden del Stack

```
        Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      descripcion_detalle(widget.value.description),
                      fila_botones(widget.value.celular,widget.value.facebook,widget.value.x,widget.value.y),
                      map(widget.value.x, widget.value.y),
                    ],
                  ),Ï
                  gradiente_fondo(widget.value.title),
                  imagen_negocio(widget.value.imageUrl),

                  ])
```

Pero ojo, no se va a mostrar debido a que tendrá otros widgets encima.

Sobre tu otra pregunta, aquí tienes el ejemplo para poner Markers:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart